# Intranet page does not scale with browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, style

The intranet page basically does not scale with the browser.. so if the browser is at 110% the white space on the right-hand side goes away, but when the browser is at say 70% the white space becomes as big as the page itself. Any idea why it wouldn't scale all of a sudden?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue in my SharePoint Online.

When you add a vertical section in the page, no web parts are added meanwhile, it shows blank by default.

Expanding the browser to more than 100% will not display the blank vertical section. In addition, only delete the vertical section will not show blank.